# polymer-cookie generates duplicate Django csrf cookie

Tags: django, polymer, django-csrf

[image]

Odd issue I just ran into. Django seems to be generating 2 cookies on when I go to this page. The two cookies doesn't have the same token, so that causes my post to fail because it's validating against the wrong cookie.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Nothing special in the view:

```
class ListingDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "bidding/listing_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        c = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c['listing'] = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=kwargs['id'])
        return self.render_to_response(c)
```

... though it seems that the offending code may be inside one of my custom components (when I hide it, the extra cookie ain't generated):

```
<polymer-element name="bts-place-bid" attributes="href">
    <template>
        <polymer-cookie id="csrfcookie" name="csrftoken"></polymer-cookie>
        <core-ajax
            id="bidxhr"
            method="post"
            body=""
            url="{{ href }}"
            headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrftoken }}"}'
            on-core-response="{{ handleResponse }}">
        </core-ajax>

        <core-style ref="bts-place-bid"></core-style>
        <paper-button on-click="{{ toggleDialog }}">Place Bid</paper-button>

        <paper-action-dialog heading="Place Bid"
                      transition="core-transition-center"
                      id="bidDialog">
            <core-style ref="bts-bid-dialog"></core-style>

            <bts-field>
                <label for="id_amount">Bid Amount in Rands</label>
                <input type="number" name="amount" id="id_amount" value="{{ amount }}">
            </bts-field>

            <bts-field vertical layout>
                <label for="id_proposal">Short note or proposal for this bid</label>
                <textarea rows="4" id="id_proposal" name="proposal" value="{{ proposal }}"></textarea>
            </bts-field>

            <paper-button dismissive><core-icon icon="cancel"></core-icon> Cancel</paper-button>
            <paper-button on-click="{{ placeBid }}" affirmative><core-icon icon="note-add"></core-icon> Place Bid!</paper-button>
        </paper-action-dialog>
        <paper-toast id="toastMsg" text=""></paper-toast>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            amount: 0,
            proposal: "",
            bidPayload: "",

            ready: function() {
                this.csrftoken = this.$.csrfcookie.value;
            },
            toggleDialog: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.bidDialog.toggle();
            },
            placeBid: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.toastMsg.text = "Placing bid, please wait..."
                this.$.toastMsg.show();

                this.$.bidxhr.body = "amount=" + this.amount + "&proposal=" + this.proposal;
                this.$.bidxhr.go();
            },
            handleResponse: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.toastMsg.text = "Bid placed, refreshing...";
                this.$.toastMsg.show();
                // Auto refresh the page...
                window.location = window.location;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I suspect the issue may be with `<polymer-cookie>`, I'll dig around it's source a bit.

Comment: Safe to assume you've already tried clearing your cache and only loading this one page? Any chance you can post your template and view code?

Comment: @dylrei added some extra bits. Yes cleared cache and this only happens on pages where I use the custom component mentioned above. I now suspect the issue may lie with <polymer-cookie>

Comment: Use a different name for your polymer-cookie. That's where you are setting a second cookie called "csrftoken"

Comment: @dylrei the <polymer-cookie> element requires me to use the name for the actual value I'm trying to retrieve, which I need to add to the headers before post. So in short I cannot change the name. I did find this issue which may be related: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-cookie/issues/6

Comment: I can't imagine why you would need to *set* two cookies with the same name, but that's the root cause of your problem. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: @dylrei that's the point; I'm _not_ setting a second cookie but a bug somewhere _is_. <polymer-cookie> allows you to set/get a cookie value. I'm trying to get an existing value, but it's bugged and instead of getting, it's setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was quite simple. Should have thought about it earlier.

I simply modified my custom component to accept a extra attribute called csrftoken, and to this attribute I can just pass the django `{{ csrf_token }}` variable. No need to look up the cookie, no need to add a extra input field etc.

Here is the final component:

```
<polymer-element name="bts-place-bid" attributes="href csrftoken">
    <template>
        <core-ajax
            id="bidxhr"
            method="post"
            body=""
            url="{{ href }}"
            headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrftoken }}"}'
            on-core-response="{{ handleResponse }}">
        </core-ajax>

        <core-style ref="bts-place-bid"></core-style>
        <paper-button on-click="{{ toggleDialog }}">Place Bid</paper-button>

        <paper-action-dialog heading="Place Bid"
                      transition="core-transition-center"
                      id="bidDialog">
            <core-style ref="bts-bid-dialog"></core-style>

            <bts-field>
                <label for="id_amount">Bid Amount in Rands</label>
                <input type="number" name="amount" id="id_amount" value="{{ amount }}">
            </bts-field>

            <bts-field vertical layout>
                <label for="id_proposal">Short note or proposal for this bid</label>
                <textarea rows="4" id="id_proposal" name="proposal" value="{{ proposal }}"></textarea>
            </bts-field>

            <paper-button dismissive><core-icon icon="cancel"></core-icon> Cancel</paper-button>
            <paper-button on-click="{{ placeBid }}" affirmative><core-icon icon="note-add"></core-icon> Place Bid!</paper-button>
        </paper-action-dialog>
        <paper-toast id="toastMsg" text=""></paper-toast>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            amount: 0,
            proposal: "",
            bidPayload: "",

            toggleDialog: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.bidDialog.toggle();
            },
            placeBid: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.toastMsg.text = "Placing bid, please wait..."
                this.$.toastMsg.show();

                this.$.bidxhr.body = "amount=" + this.amount + "&proposal=" + this.proposal;
                this.$.bidxhr.go();
            },
            handleResponse: function(ev, detail, sender) {
                this.$.toastMsg.text = "Bid placed, refreshing...";
                this.$.toastMsg.show();
                // Auto refresh the page...
                window.location = window.location;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

... and this is then used in the main django template as such:

```
<bts-place-bid href="{% url 'bidding_listing_bid' id=listing.id %}"
               csrftoken="{{ csrf_token }}"></bts-place-bid>
```

Answer (score 1):

So... you are definitely creating this second cookie. It's not a bug. But let's see if we can't get you back on track.

The source for polymer-cookie shows several "hidden" attributes:

```
<polymer-element name="polymer-cookie" hidden attributes="name value expires secure domain path max-age">
```

The cookie you're setting has the same name as the CSRF token, but an arbitrary value. So the easiest fix probably is to specify the value you want it to have:

```
<polymer-cookie id="csrfcookie" name="csrftoken" value="{{ csrftoken }}"></polymer-cookie>
```

I'd expect that you will still have duplicate cookies, but at least now they will have the same value.

As for how you *should* do this... skip polymer-cookie and just put `{% csrftoken %}` in your template. That will create a hidden input with the name "csrfmiddlewaretoken" that you can inspect the value of on the client side. Then you can return that value with your ajax POSTs.